# How can I prevent an image from scaling down when the user zooms out?

Tags: html, css

I have a  object in HTML that is 200px by 200px. When the user zooms out, the image gets smaller. How can I make it so that when the user zooms their browser out, the image size stays the same?
I don't care if it gets larger when zoomed in, I just need a solution to prevent the image from getting smaller when zoomed out.
Here is what the related HTML looks like:

```html
<div class="player">
   <img src="./avatars/Avatar2.png" class="playerimage">
</div>
```

And the related classes with related properties look like this:

```css
.player {
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* The player image is 1000px by 1000px but we scale it down */
.playerimage {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

I have tried using min-width and min-height CSS values but this didn't work.
Here is what the image looks like when the browser is at 100%: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10G57.png)

And this is what it looks like at 50% zoom:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7hRX.png)

Comment: dont set the width in fixed units such as `px` but a relative unit such as `%` or `vw/vh`. you can maintain a square by using `aspect-ratio` or not setting the height at all when the image is a square by default.

Comment: I'll try the aspect ratio thing you mentioned, but I have tried setting it to a percent but it caused a really weird issue where the closer the image was to the top right the smaller it would get. I'm not sure about vw and vh though.

Comment: Keep in mind that `aspect-ratio` which @tacoshy mentioned is still a relatively new CSS property and browser support is [not super great](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio).

Comment: @micahlt that is only semi correct. The only browser that does not support aspect-ratio is the IE11 (which can use it with vendor prefix) that has been deprecated since august 2021.

Comment: @tacoshy assuming that everyone is running the latest version of their browser.   Caniuse determines that around 80% of users have a compatible browser, which is good, but also not great.  Depending on the number of users the site has it should really have a polyfill.

Comment: @micahlt 85% and further 14% where the support is listed as unknown (but they actually support this). Thats why I said that only IE support it. Of course if you use a deprecated browser version from 2006 still... Thumb rule, you need to support the common browsers. Supporting outdated browsers from 2006 will be a pain for literally everything.

Comment: It may be a pain, but many companies still require support for older browsers.  Also, many browsers that don't support it were updated as recently as 2020 - not 2006.  Again, I think it really depends on the scope of the project, its users, and how it's being used.  As the code appears to be for a game, it would appear that widespread usability isn't a big concern in which case you'd be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by setting only width or height in vw/vh responsive units.

```css
.player {
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.playerimage {
  width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <img src="https://workmacro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/1-by-1-1024x1024.png" alt="" class="playerimage">
</div>
```

Here's a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/desper-18/pen/oNoQpze)

Comment: you dont need to wrap the image in a container. You can declare `position: absolute` directly on the container. (Yes I'm aware that you just copied the code)

Comment: In my environment the .player position is set using %. Using this causes positioning issues.

Comment: Could it be possible to have the player image be a div and use background to display the image along with some other properties to enforce the size?